# Excluding record ID from the URL and let controller handle/get/guess it one way or another

Tags: symfony

As you can see below I'm creating a webform to update a selected person's record. All work fine but I just want to know if my logic (generating form action URL with person's ID attached to it) is a good practise or not. If someone fiddles with the form action URL and changes the ID from 21 to 69, my code would potentially update someone else's record. How can I avoid it?

1. User clicks a person's link [`http:..../person/update/21`] which
   takes him to update form. This calls `indexAction($personId)` as you
   can see below and pulls the data from database to populate the web
   form.
2. User then do the changes and submits the form. Form action URL is
   [`http:..../person/update/process/21`]

**CLASS**

```
class UpdateController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($personId)
    {
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CiTiBundle:Person');
        $person = $repo->findOneBy(array('personId' => $personId));

        $form = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $person,
                array('action' => $this->generateUrl('process', array('personId' => $personId))));

        return $this->render('CiTiBundle:Default:update.html.twig',
                array('page' => 'Update', 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function updateAction(Request $request, $personId)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('CiTiBundle:Person');
        $person = $repo->find($personId);

        $form = $this->getForm($person, $personId);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $submission = $form->getData();

            $person->setFirstname($submission->getFirstname());
            $person->setMiddlename($submission->getMiddlename());

            $em->persist($person);
            $em->flush();

            exit('WELL DONE!');
        }

        exit('WHAT!');
    }
}
```

Comment: In your controller action you may need to check if the current user ID is not equal to the sent user ID throw an access denied exception.

Comment: How and on which line?

Comment: I know you mean this code but how do I get _current user ID_? `if ($id != $currentUserId) { exit('Pisss'); }`

Comment: This is to get the current active user `$current_user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();`

Comment: `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in ...`

Comment: `print_r(get_class_methods($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()));` returns nothing. There is no `getUser()` in it.

Comment: That means you do not have any user session; Do you have any user class, or any authentication method for your app?

Comment: No. I'm writing a simple CRUD application to enhance my symfony knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to add to `CiTiBundle:Person` a property `hashid` and use it as key to identify the Person.

So:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="hashid", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $hashid;
```

You can initialize `hashid` in the constructor like this

```
public function __construct() {
    $token_generator = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\UriSafeTokenGenerator();
    $this->hashid = substr(base64_encode($token_generator->generateToken()), 0, 20);
    // Of course you can choose a different logic/function. You just have to be sure that is unique.
}
```

Now you can create your link using hash instead of IDs `{{ path('person_edit', { 'hash': entity.hashid }) }}` and of course in your controller to retrieve the `Person` from the repository you search by `hashid`

In this way users can't edit other entities changing the URLs